# using adsisearcher to find computer name in domain if exist or not and return a value to result = true

Tags: powershell, dns, find

my script is trying to check if you entered a computer neme

```
$credObjects = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $userNames, $passwords
    $Credential = Get-Credential -Credential $credObjects
    $Searcher = New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
    $searcher = [adsisearcher]"(&(objectCategory=computer)(objectClass=computer)(name=$global:NewComputerName))"
    $searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(('name'))
    $searchResult = $searcher.FindAll()
    if($searchResult.count -eq 1)
     {
      $Result = $true
     }
      else
    {
      $Result = $False
    }
```

and them use it in if statement to popup message

```
elseif ($Result -match 'true')
        {
        $msgBoxInput7 = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('computer is exist', 'OK')
    
         switch  ($msgBoxInput7) {

        'OK' {
                    $groupbox1.ResumeLayout()
                    $form1.ResumeLayout()
                    $form1.add_FormClosed($Form_Cleanup_FormClosed)
    }
  }
        }
```

any help to make it work

Comment: What is the problem you're having?

Comment: Its not working the result is always true or always false, is there any modification to the code to make it working

Comment: Which result? Please describe _what are you expecting to happen_ and _what actually happens_ - no one but you can see your screen :)

Comment: Ok when i enter a computer name the script check AD and if exist show message box say this pc is exist if not exist rename the pc to what I entered for input

Comment: And what is currently happening? Does it say "computer is exist" when the computer doesn't exist?

Comment: It say it exist but it’s not

Comment: Any help please

Answer (score 0):

the code is working fine if i run script in admin in powershell
but when run it as user not working as expected